# JavaCC - Simple expression

Tags: java

What should my void decleration() if possible string input is parsed based on the image.

```
SKIP :
{
< " " | "\t" | "\r" | "\n" | "\r\n" >
| <"//" (~["\n","\r"])* ("\n"|"\r"|"\r\n") >
| <"/*"(~["/"])*  "*""/" >
}
TOKEN : { < VAR: "VAR" > }
TOKEN : { < AS: "AS" >}
TOKEN : /* KEYWORDS */
{
    < TYPE: "INT"| "BOOL"|"FLOAT" >
}

TOKEN :
{
  < EQUALS: "=" >
}
TOKEN:
{
  < PLUS : "+" >|< MINUS :"-" >|< MUL: "*" >|< DIV: "/" >|< COMM: ",">
}
TOKEN:
{
    < VARIABLE: (["a"-"z", "A"-"Z", "0"-"9"])+ >
}

void decleration(): {} { <VAR> (<VARIABLE>|< COMM >|<EQUALS>)+ <AS> <TYPE>}
```

I'm still new to JavaCC, so please forgive my code it its bad, Where can I find some sources on making custom compiler using JavaCC.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a tutorial [here](https://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-Tutorial/javacc-tutorial.pdf).

To parse the example you've given in your question, you will need:

- to add "CHAR" in token `TYPE`,
- to add "_" in token `VARIABLE`. Actually i would rewrite it because it also accepts integers. I would do something like this:

> ```
> TOKEN:
> {
>     < VARIABLE: <LETTER>(<LETTER>|<DIGIT>)* >
>     | < #LETTER: ["a"-"z", "A"-"Z", "_"] >
>     | < #DIGIT: ["0"-"9"] >
> }
> ```

- to add a non-terminal production method for a declaration list:

> ```
> void input(): {} { (declaration())* }
> ```

- to add the tokens for the initial value. This could be a complex expression, but you will need at least the literal values for INT, CHAR, FLOAT and strings (like "TRUE" in your example):

> ```
> TOKEN:
> {
>     < INT_VALUE: (<DIGIT>)+ >
>     | < FLOAT_VALUE: <INT_VALUE> "." (<DIGIT>)* | "." (<DIGIT>)+ >
>     | < CHAR_VALUE: "\'" (~["\'","\\"]|<ESCAPE>) "\'" >
>     | < STRING_VALUE: "\"" (~["\'","\\"]|<ESCAPE>)* "\"" >
>     | < #ESCAPE: "\\" ["n","t","b","r","f","\\","\"","\'"] >
> }
> ```

- add the production rules for the variable initial values:

> ```
> void varDeclaration(): {} { <VARIABLE> (<EQUALS> literalValue())? }
> void literalValue(): {} { <INT_VALUE> | <FLOAT_VALUE> | <CHAR_VALUE> | <STRING_VALUE> }
> ```

the declaration rule becomes:

> ```
> void declaration(): {} { <VAR> varDeclaration() (< COMM > varDeclaration())* <AS> <TYPE>}
> ```

Note that, as you skip the the end of line characters, nothing prevents the presence of several declarations on the same line.

The resulting file looks like this:

> ```
> options {
>     STATIC = false;
>     OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = "src/parser";
> }
> PARSER_BEGIN(Parser)
> package parser;
> public class Parser {
>     public void parse() throws ParseException {
>         input();
>     }
> }
> PARSER_END(Parser)
>
> SKIP :
> {
> < " " | "\t" | "\r" | "\n" | "\r\n" >
> | <"//" (~["\n","\r"])* ("\n"|"\r"|"\r\n") >
> | <"/*"(~["/"])*  "*""/" >
> }
> TOKEN : { < VAR: "VAR" > }
> TOKEN : { < AS: "AS" >}
> TOKEN : /* KEYWORDS */
> {
>     < TYPE: "INT" | "BOOL" | "FLOAT" | "CHAR" >
> }
>
> TOKEN :
> {
>   < EQUALS: "=" >
> }
> TOKEN:
> {
>   < PLUS : "+" >|< MINUS :"-" >|< MUL: "*" >|< DIV: "/" >|< COMM: ",">
> }
> TOKEN:
> {
>     < VARIABLE: <LETTER>(<LETTER>|<DIGIT>)* >
>     | < #LETTER: ["a"-"z", "A"-"Z", "_"] >
>     | < #DIGIT: ["0"-"9"] >
> }
> TOKEN:
> {
>     < INT_VALUE: (<DIGIT>)+ >
>     | < FLOAT_VALUE: <INT_VALUE> "." (<DIGIT>)* | "." (<DIGIT>)+ >
>     | < CHAR_VALUE: "\'" (~["\'","\\"]|<ESCAPE>) "\'" >
>     | < STRING_VALUE: "\"" (~["\'","\\"]|<ESCAPE>)* "\"" >
>     | < #ESCAPE: "\\" ["n","t","b","r","f","\\","\"","\'"] >
> }
>
> void input(): {} { (declaration())* }
> void varDeclaration(): {} { <VARIABLE> (<EQUALS> literalValue())? }
> void literalValue(): {} { <INT_VALUE> | <FLOAT_VALUE> | <CHAR_VALUE> | <STRING_VALUE> }
> void declaration(): {} { <VAR> varDeclaration() (< COMM > varDeclaration())* <AS> <TYPE>}
> ```

UPDATE

To add the body part; from what i see, the input is a list of declarations followed by a body:

> void input(): {} { (declaration())*  body() }

and the body rule would be something like:

```
void body(): {} { <START> (statement())* <STOP> }
```

You need a few more tokens: keywords "START", "STOP", "OUTPUT", "AND", "OR", "NOT", operators ":", "&", "(", ")", etc...

I see two types of statements: assignments and output statements:

```
void statement(): {} { assignment() | output() }
void assignment(): {} { <VARIABLE> <EQUALS> expression() }
void output(): {} { <OUTPUT> <COLON> expression() }
```

They both require the rules for an expression. It could look like this:

```
void expression(): {} { comparison() (logicalOp() comparison())* }
void logicalOp(): {} { <AND> | <OR> }
void comparison(): {} { simpleExpression() ( comparisonOp() simpleExpression() )? }
void comparisonOp(): {} { <LT> | <GT> | <LE> | <GE> | <EQ> | <NE> }
void simpleExpression(): {} { term() ( addOp() term() )* }
void addOp(): {} { <PLUS> | <MINUS> | <CAT> }
void term(): {} { factor() ( mulOp() factor() )* }
void mulOp(): {} { <MUL> | <DIV> | <MOD> }
void factor(): {} {
    (<PLUS>|<MINUS>) factor()
    | <LPAR> expression() <RPAR>
    | <NOT> expression()
    | <VARIABLE>
    | literalValue()
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
options {
    STATIC = false;
    OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = "src/parser";
}
PARSER_BEGIN(Parser)
package parser;
public class Parser {
    public void parse() throws ParseException {
        input();
    }
}
PARSER_END(Parser)

SKIP :
{
< " " | "\t" | "\r" | "\n" | "\r\n" >
| <"//" (~["\n","\r"])* ("\n"|"\r"|"\r\n") >
| <"/*"(~["/"])*  "*""/" >
}
TOKEN : { < VAR: "VAR" > }
TOKEN : { < AS: "AS" >}
TOKEN : { < START: "START" > | < STOP: "STOP" > | < OUTPUT: "OUTPUT" > } 
TOKEN : /* KEYWORDS */
{
    <INT: "INT">|<BOOL:"BOOL">|<FLOAT:"FLOAT">|<CHAR:"CHAR">
    |<AND: "AND"> | <OR: "OR"> | <NOT: "NOT">
}

TOKEN :
{
  < EQUALS: "=" > | < COLON: ":" > | <LPAR: "(">|<RPAR: ")">
}
TOKEN:
{
  < PLUS : "+" >|< MINUS :"-" >|< MUL: "*" >|< DIV: "/" >|< MOD: "%" >|< COMM: ",">
  |<LT: "<">|<GT: ">">|<LE: "<=">|<GE: ">=">|<EQ: "==">|<NE: "<>">
  |<CAT: "&">
}
TOKEN:
{
    < VARIABLE: <LETTER>(<LETTER>|<DIGIT>)* >
    | < #LETTER: ["a"-"z", "A"-"Z", "_"] >
    | < #DIGIT: ["0"-"9"] >
}
TOKEN:
{
    < INT_VALUE: (<DIGIT>)+ >
    | < FLOAT_VALUE: <INT_VALUE> "." (<DIGIT>)* | "." (<DIGIT>)+ >
    | < CHAR_VALUE: "\'" (~["\'","\\"]|<ESCAPE>) "\'" >
    | < STRING_VALUE: "\"" (~["\"","\\"]|<ESCAPE>)* "\"" >
    | < #ESCAPE: "\\" ["n","t","b","r","f","\\","\"","\'"] >
}

void input(): {} { (declaration())*  body() }
void varDeclaration(): {} { <VARIABLE> (<EQUALS> literalValue())?  }
void literalValue(): {} { <INT_VALUE> | <FLOAT_VALUE> | <CHAR_VALUE> | <STRING_VALUE> }
void declaration(): {} { <VAR> varDeclaration() (<COMM> varDeclaration())* <AS> type()}
void type(): {} {<INT>|<FLOAT>|<BOOL>|<CHAR>}
void body(): {} { <START> (statement())* <STOP> }
void statement(): {} { assignment() | output() }
void assignment(): {} { <VARIABLE> <EQUALS> expression() }
void output(): {} { <OUTPUT> <COLON> expression() }
void expression(): {} { comparison() (logicalOp() comparison())* }
void logicalOp(): {} { <AND> | <OR> }
void comparison(): {} { simpleExpression() ( comparisonOp() simpleExpression() )? }
void comparisonOp(): {} { <LT> | <GT> | <LE> | <GE> | <EQ> | <NE> }
void simpleExpression(): {} { term() ( addOp() term() )* }
void addOp(): {} { <PLUS> | <MINUS> | <CAT> }
void term(): {} { factor() ( mulOp() factor() )* }
void mulOp(): {} { <MUL> | <DIV> | <MOD> }
void factor(): {} {
    (<PLUS>|<MINUS>) factor()
    | <LPAR> expression() <RPAR>
    | <NOT> expression()
    | <VARIABLE>
    | literalValue()
}
```

Comment: thank you for the effort I really appreciate it, If I have to add another set of rules to accept [link](https://imgur.com/a/B4l7l) input (body, from image), should I insert it in `void input(): {} { (declaration())* }` like `void input(): {} { (declaration())*|(expression()) }`?

Comment: @XavierJohanis this would match either a set of declarations, or an expression (one and only one). With this rule: `void input(): {} { (declaration())*  body() }` you have a (possibly empty) list of declarations followed with a body. The body rule would be: `void body(): {} { <START> (statement())* <STOP> }`

Comment: Thank you for the effort, though is it necessary to put `PARSER_BEGIN(Parser) PARSER_END(Parser)` because it seems like keywords like var are not case-sensitive? and start and stop can be switched.

Comment: @XavierJohanis to ignore case, you can add the option IGNORE_CASE = true;, it has nothing to do with the PARSER_BEGIN and PARSER_END. What do you mean by switching start and stop?

Comment: If input is [this](https://imgur.com/a/QRTa5) the program should output error because the rule is START then STOP

Comment: @XavierJohanis yes: I'm getting an exception: `parser.ParseException: Encountered " "STOP" "STOP "" at line 3, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    "VAR" ...
    "START" ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164825/discussion-between-xavier-johanis-and-maurice-perry).